# Relations are not drawn in pst-asr

Tags: pstricks, pst-asr

I'm trying for a while now to compile a part of the documentation code of pst-asr.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-asr}

\textwidth=6in
\oddsidemargin=.25in
\evensidemargin=.25in
\rightskip=0pt plus 2em

\newpsstyle{bigsyls}{extragap=.6ex,unitxgap=true,xgap=3.5ex,
   ts=0pt ($\times$),sy=5.5ex ($\sigma$) .7ex,ph=-4.5ex (pf)}
\newpsstyle{dotted}{linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1.2pt,dotsep=1.6pt}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$}
\def\crossing{\pscircle[linestyle=solid,linewidth=.5pt](0,0){.7ex}}%

\newdimen\dimpuba
\newdimen\dimpubb
\newcount\exno
\exno=0
\def\ex{%
   \vskip2.5em
   \allowbreak\noindent
   \global\advance\exno by 1
   \bgroup
   \parindent=0pt (\the\exno)\quad
}
\def\xe{\par\egroup}
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\ex
\asr logwhin\endasr
\TO
\asr \3logwhin\endasr
\bigskip

\hfill \TO
\asr \3log\2wVhin\endasr
\TO
\asr \3log\2wV\3hin\endasr \kern1em
\xe

\end{document}
```

I am using TexStudio with XeLaTeX and can't manage for it to display the connection lines that is supposed to show (pic from documentation):
[image]

mine only looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please check your examples compile before uploading them! It is always easy to forget something crucial. I've made two obvious corrections but I leave you to check for subtler errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with an up-to-date of TeXLive 2016. However, put
`\listfiles` as first line into your document and compare the list (at the end of your logfile) with the following one:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pst-asr.sty    2011/04/20 v1.6 LaTex wrapper pst-asr.tex (JF)
pstricks.sty    2015/11/14 v0.62 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/
JK)
pstricks.tex    2016/06/09 v2.68 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2016/06/09 v2.68 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro    2012/10/16 v. 1.15, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro    2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro    2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
```

[image]